Declaring a Javascript Array containing Objects
Is there a way I can declare an object array like this [{}]?
So in the following Code:


 club = {};
 club.player_DB                 = [{}]; // Player Database;
        
 // club.player_DB[0] = {};
 club.player_DB[0].code         = 44;
 console.log(club.player_DB[0].code);
            
 // club.player_DB[1] = {};
 club.player_DB[1].code         = 21;
        
 console.log(club.player_DB[0].code+" "+club.player_DB[1].code);    



I have declared the club.playerDB with [{}], i.e an array that contains an object;
Or do I have to declare the object on each array (commented out {} declaration) for each player.
Thanks.

You don't have to declare variable type at all in JavaScript. Any variable may contain a value of any type. Initializations like yours don't hurt anything but they are completely unnecessary.

I am not sure I understand.  I am trying to build what amounts to a database of players, each array represents a player that in turn has an object, i.e. player_DB[0].goals etc.

Yes you need the lines you have commented out, in order to create those array elements before you try to access them. Actually, you have already created the first array element with =[{}], so you don't need the _DB[0] = {}, but any index other than [0] you would first need to create before accessing.

What Pointy means in their comment is that you can do this:


const club = {};
club.player_DB = [{}]; // Declare an array containing an object.

club.player_DB[0] = 42; // Then assign a number.

console.log(club.player_DB);  // No trace of the object.



However, as Ray Wallace explains, you cannot access a property of an undefined object, so you do need to allocate your array elements before adding any properties to them:


const club = {player_DB: [{}]};
        
club.player_DB[0].code = 44;  // The first element already exists.

club.player_DB[1] = {code: 21};

club.player_DB.push({code: 13});
        
console.log(club.player_DB[0].code+" "+club.player_DB[1].code+" "+club.player_DB[2].code);



Also note that I added the const keyword to the club object initialisation to avoid declaring it in the global scope.
